# Counting each line in a textfile

Tags: vb.net, isolatedstorage, lines, counting

So I'm a bit stuck with this. Basically I've got a text file in a directory and in that text file, I've added different text in each of its line. I'm trying to use this to count how many lines there are in that text file. I'm using `IsolatedStorageFile` to do this and this is how I'm accessing it.

So far I've got this but It's not working:

```
Using isoComments As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("textfile1.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore)
        Using readerComments As StreamReader = New StreamReader(isoComments)
            For Each line In readerComments.ReadLine
                MessageBox.Show(line.ToString.Count)
            Next
        End Using
End Using
```

The result is not the amount of lines instead, the amount of characters in each line. This is not what I want I want the number of lines in that particular textfile. Is anyone able to help me with this.

Comment: `line.ToString` returns the curren line string ,so whn using this `line.ToString.Count` you get the length of that string. So basically you just have to count the `line` . work around with that.try to remove your message box inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim iLineCount As Integer
iLineCount = 0

Using isoComments As IsolatedStorageFileStream = 
New IsolatedStorageFileStream("textfile1.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore)
    Using readerComments As StreamReader = New StreamReader(isoComments)
        For Each line In readerComments.ReadLine
            iLineCount=iLineCount+1
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(iLineCount)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: seems like it counted the number of text in the first line rather than all the lines.

Comment: No you counted the number of text for every line, not just the first line.

Comment: Can't seem to be getting the result. In my textfile it looks like this :8F2689723C3745
A4BBB8892DF843
C2199855351740
1D1EDF3D29B14E Each of those are in different lines, since there are 14 characters, it will show 14.

Comment: Can you post an example text file in your original question with formatting? A 'line' is actually just a carriage return character. If your text file has 14 carriage return characters the could should return 14.

Comment: I've decided to remove the old method and add a new one and it works perfectly. Sorry for the late notice, I'll update my answer when I get time. Thank you for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this problem. My original idea was to get the amount of times a textfile was edited and so I figured adding something in each line of that textfile and counting each line would help but i couldn't find a way to it.

What I did was I added a counter which increases by 1 everytime it saves and then when it's read +1 is added to it. That way I have an exact number of times it was edited because everytime the textfile is edited, like mentioned before, it increases like a counter by 1. so if the user edited the textfile about 12 times then there will be the number 12 in the file and that will be read when the ser decides to edit the textfile again, once he saves +1 to the 12 will be added maing it 13.

I used this method to do the increment by one:

```
Using isoStream As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("textfile.text", FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore) Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(isoStream)
      Dim i As Integer
      i += 1
      writer.WriteLine(i)
  End Using
End Using
```